# checkbox styling doesn't work after form submission

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am styling the checkbox using CSS. 
The form is rendered correctly when the page loads. When I submit the form after checking a few check-boxes, I am rendering the form with a state with prev form.

After the form submission the Checkbox doesn't seem to work.

The code is,

```
<input id="box_53d76a6f6d696e1f8e0f0000" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" title="Basement" name="room_ids[]" value="53d76a6f6d696e1f8e0f0000">
```

Comment: What do you mean by `prev form`?

Comment: "After the form submission the Checkbox doesnt seem to work" - yeah, your page is very broken.

Comment: @Xlander sorry i mean before submission

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you please point where can i start to fix the issue

Comment: @RubyOnRails: controls disabled like this, I suspect that click handlers are not wired up after the submission. Look in that direction.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i am rendering the same page after submission. Before submission i can check and uncheck any of the checkboxes.

Comment: Well, I don't know what else to tell you. Time for some debugging! :) You can get help with that on sites like http://codementor.io or http://airpair.com (that will cost you, though)

Comment: Please improve your question. Explain what you expect and what happens instead. Also post all involved code snippets. Otherwise help is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Same ID on the Search Results as well.

```
<div class="box" id='box_53fc182969702d52040f0000'> <div class="pull-left">Basement</div> <div class="close"></div> <div class="clearfix"></div> </div>
```

Checkbox IDs

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="box_53fc182969702d52040f0000" value="53fc182969702d52040f0000" name="room_ids[]" title="Basement" checked="checked"/>
```

When you click the Label the `FOR` value is right now addressing the `div.box` not the `input = checkbox.`